# Computing Conditional Characteristic Function

Tags: probability, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I am trying to compute the characteristic function of the following:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that
$Y\mid X = x\sim N(0, x)$ with $X\sim\mathrm{Po}(\lambda)$. Find the characteristic function of $Y$.

I know the characteristic function is $\varphi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]=\int e^{itx}f_X(x) \, dx$.  How do I take into account the fact that $Y$ is conditional on $X$ to compute the characteristic function?

In my case I need to find $f_Y(y)$ in order to solve $\varphi_Y(t)=E[e^{itY}]=\int e^{ity}f_Y(y) \, dy$.

To find the probability density of y, I need to solve $P(Y=y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(Y|X=x)*P(X=x)$, but I don't know how to reduce this.

Comment: I changed $Y|X=x$~$N(0,x)$ to $Y\mid X=x\sim N(0,x)$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Why you don't found the density of $y$?

Comment: $\varphi_X(t)$ is not $E[e^{itx}]$; rather it is $E[e^{itX}]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(e^{itY}\mid X=x)  & = \operatorname{E}(e^{it\sqrt{x} \, Z})\quad\text{where }Z\sim N(0,1), \\[10pt]
& = \varphi_Z(t\sqrt x) = \exp \left( \frac{-1}2 t^2 x \right).
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(e^{itY}) & = \operatorname{E} \left( \operatorname{E}(e^{itY}\mid X) \right) = \operatorname{E}\left( \exp\left( \frac{-1}2 t^2 X \right) \right) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{-t^2 x/2} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\left( e^{-t^2/2} \lambda \right)^x}{x!} \\[10pt]
& = e^{-\lambda} e^{e^{-t^2 \lambda/2}},
\end{align}
or a bit more legibly,
$$
\exp( -\lambda)\exp\left(\lambda \exp \left( \frac{-t^2} 2 \right)\right).
$$

Comment: In your last step where you rearrange for legibility shouldn't you have $exp(-\lambda+exp(\frac{-t^2\lambda}{2}))$ since you are taking the product of two exponentials when you combine them you should get a sum in the exponent?

Comment: @user75514 : Sorry --- I was hasty.  I've edited.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's actually $e^{-\lambda \left(1-\exp(\frac{-t^2}{2})\right)}$

Comment: @d.k.o. : What are your views on the current edit? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeap. The OP has another question which is based on this answer. Now it should work,,,