# Showing Convergence in Distribution for Conditional Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that
$Y | X = x$ ~ $N(0, x)$ with $X$ ~ $Po(\lambda$). Show that $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution as $n \to \infty$.

The first step was to determine the characteristic function of Y, which I asked about here: [Computing Conditional Characteristic Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342796/computing-conditional-characteristic-function).  The characteristic function of Y ends up being $\varphi_{Y}(t)=$$
\exp\left( -\lambda \exp\left( \frac{-t^2\lambda} 2 \right) \right).
$

So far I know I am supposed to use that fact that $e^x=\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{\lambda}$ in my solution.  So if I try to expand the characteristic function using this identity, I have $\varphi_{Y}(t)=\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\left(-\lambda e^{\frac{-t^2\lambda}{2}}\right)}{\lambda}\right)^{\lambda}$.  Now I need to show $\frac{\varphi_{Y}(t)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{ \left(-\lambda e^{\frac{-t^2\lambda}{2}}\right)}{\lambda}\right)^{\lambda}}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \to e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}$.  This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: that fact $e^x = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{1 + x}{\lambda}\bigg)^\lambda$ is a strange one, are you sure about that?

Comment: maybe the characteristic function of a poisson is $$\varphi_Y(t) = e^{\lambda(e^{it} - 1)}$$

Comment: There was a typo.  I am trying to apply the identity $e^x=lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.

Comment: what about the poisson characteristic function?

Comment: What does depend on $n$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$ then

$$\varphi_{Y/\sqrt{\lambda}}(t)=\varphi_{Y}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)=e^{-\lambda(1-\exp\{-\frac{t^2}{2\lambda}\})}\rightarrow e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

because

$$\left(1-\frac{\lambda(1-\exp\{-\frac{t^2}{2\lambda}\})}{\lambda}\right)^\lambda=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$